# To create a cross-difference matrix with for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

Let you have the following arrays

```
vec_1 <- c('a','b','c')
vec_2 <- c('d','e','f')
vec_3 <- c('g','h','i')
vec_4 <- c('l','m','n')
```

in a matrix `X` like this one:

```
X <- matrix(c(vec_1, vec_2, vec_3, vec_4), nrow = 3, byrow = FALSE)
```

which is equal to

```
> X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "d"  "g"  "l" 
[2,] "b"  "e"  "h"  "m" 
[3,] "c"  "f"  "i"  "n"
```

I would like to use a `for()` loop to get the following matrix `D`:

```
D <- matrix(c('a - d', 'b - e', 'c - f',
              'a - g', 'b - h', 'c - i',
              'a - l', 'b - m', 'c - n',
              'd - g', 'e - h', 'f - i',
              'd - l', 'e - m', 'f - n',
              'g - l', 'h - m', 'i - n'),
            nrow = 3, byrow = FALSE)
```

which, as you can see, is made up by the cross difference of each `X` column:

```
> D
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]   
[1,] "a - d" "a - g" "a - l" "d - g" "d - l" "g - l"
[2,] "b - e" "b - h" "b - m" "e - h" "e - m" "h - m"
[3,] "c - f" "c - i" "c - n" "f - i" "f - n" "i - n"
```

In my underlying problem each letter is a numeric value.

How may I achieve this result using a `for()` loop?

Please, replace each letter with a random number if it's useful to answer the question, you don't need to go crazy with `paste()`!

Comment: Are you just trying to get `paste("column", 1:N)`?

Comment: You'll probably get a good answer if you define the underlying problem for which you need such a solution. On its own, @Thomas has told you all you need to know... ( `paste("column", 1:(N+3))` )

Comment: I am not, because the number of rows marked with `"column x"` should be `N * (N - 1) / 2` according to my calculations.

Comment: Your question is not clear then. E.g., It mentions matrices, but doesn't provide any.

Comment: Ok, I am going to edit the question to show you the whole problem.

Comment: Edited, is it better now?

Comment: @LisaAnn yes it is. Interesting problem +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick....

```
m <- matrix( 1:12 , nrow = 3 , byrow = FALSE )
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    4    7   10
#[2,]    2    5    8   11
#[3,]    3    6    9   12

t( apply( m , 1 , function(x) { tmp <- t( outer(x,x,"-") ) ; tmp[ lower.tri(tmp) ]} ) )
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   -3   -6   -9   -3   -6   -3
#[2,]   -3   -6   -9   -3   -6   -3
#[3,]   -3   -6   -9   -3   -6   -3
```

There must be loads of better ways to accomplish this, but I can't think of them right now. Basically we calculate the `outer` difference row by row across the numeric matrix. We transpose (to deal with the fact that you filled your matrix column-wise) and then extract the lower triangle from the result.

Comment: It may be marginally faster, esp. on a large matrix, to have `function(x) { tmp <- outer(x,x,"-") ; rev(tmp[ upper.tri(tmp) ])}`.

Comment: Nice stuff, and considering `apply()` is like a wrapper for `for()` loop I think it's perfectly in-topic.